# Inserting HTML into canvas without creating CORS restriction

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, cors

I am trying to get the image data from a canvas to which I added a HTML element's data by using [MDN's method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas#JavaScript). After I insert the HTML data, I can't access the canvas' image data anymore though (in Chrome):

```js
//This function is a direct copy of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas#JavaScript
onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
      '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
      '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:14px">' +
      'example' +
      '</div>' +
      '</foreignObject>' +
      '</svg>';

  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  var img = new Image();
  var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    getData(ctx);
  };

  img.src = url;
};

//the part where it goes wrong:
function getData(ctx) {
  try {
    ctx.getImageData(0,0,100,100);
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

My question is: is it possible to insert the HTML data, and still be able to access the image data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around a bit more, I found out that `data:` URIs do still permit access to image data after inserting the exact same bit of HTML. Even though `data:` URIs are slower than `blob`s, this does seem like the best way to go here.

```js
onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
      '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
      '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:14px">' +
      'example' +
      '</div>' +
      '</foreignObject>' +
      '</svg>';
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
  var img = new Image();
  var url = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(data);

  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    getData(ctx);
  };
  img.src = url;
};

function getData(ctx) {
  try {
    ctx.getImageData(0,0,100,100);
    alert('Finished without errors');
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the canvas becomes tainted with the SVG and therefore `context.getImageData` is no longer allowed. This has become necessary because of cross-domain security issues.

The (sometimes unsatisfactory) workaround is to bounce the html off your server and use a headless browser (I recommend PhantomJS) to convert the html into an image. Then serve that image back to the client.  Since the html-as-image is not cross-domain, it will not taint the canvas and you can use `context.getImageData`.

Comment: Ok, but isn't there some other way to do it then? Adding svg data to a canvas works just fine as long as it doesn't contain a foreignobject, so isn't there another way to insert html things and still access the image data?

Comment: I guess I'll have to deal with that then. I'd rather have avoided server-side processing, but if it's the only way, I guess I have no choice.

Comment: Yep, the bad guys have ruined html-capturing for us.  Future browsers are working to relax the CORS restrictions, but they haven't completed their fixes yet.

Comment: I've found another way to avoid using server-side processing and still achieve the desired result (see my answer). I'll move my 'accept' to that when it's possible because it's what I ended up using, so I apologise for the -15 rep.

Comment: No problem here...glad you got it sorted! :-) While your new technique will not enable the full range of html+css, it will work for basic layout stuff including word wrapping. Cheers!